# Executing a Process in a Specific Directory

Tags: c#, process

I need to execute a process in `c:\`. When I use `Process.Processstartinfo` it doesn't execute from `c:\` and so its dependencies can't be found. It runs in my app's directory instead. How can I run it in the `c:\` directory?

Comment: I think you don't need `g++` tag for this question. And please share people what have you already tried. You can/should read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx)?

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"MyWorkingDirectoryPath";
```

e.g.:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.WorkingDirectory =  @"MyWorkingDirectoryPath";

// set additional properties 

Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
```

> When the `UseShellExecute` property is false, gets or sets the working
>   directory for the process to be started. When `UseShellExecute` is
>   true, gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be
>   started.

Comment: What mean Workingdirectory its directory that process start and work

Comment: That not work i try i have app .exe i test it open input.txt and  write text in input.txt to output.txt and it doesnt create output.txt in c:\(working directory)

Answer (score 0):

Set `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to the working directory of the process you want to launch, i.e. in your case `"C:\"`.